# How to make my workspace match another commit like "hg revert -r [commit] --all"

Tags: git

Without changing which commit I have checked out, how can I set my entire working directory to a different commit?

In mercurial, I would do this with `hg revert -r [commit] --all`.

Comment: `git checkout <id> -- .`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Make it an answer, instead of a comment, and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git checkout` with a path; e.g. '.' for the complete actual working directory:

```
git checkout <commit-id> -- .
```